# Why I am unable to call helper function from afterRender in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-renderer

I'm trying to call a helper function when `window.resize` event is fired, but it is not happening.

```
afterRender : function(component,event,helper){
    this.superAfterRender();
    //window.addEventListener("resize", helper.onRender(component,event));
    window.onresize = function(component,event,helper){
        helper.onRender(component,event,helper);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Custom renderer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm) `afterRender` function accepts two, not three parameters

```
afterRender: function (component, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();
    // interact with the DOM here
}
```

So, you need to change your code as following:

```
afterRender : function(component, helper){
    this.superAfterRender();
    //window.addEventListener("resize", helper.onRender(component));
    window.onresize = function(component,helper){
        helper.onRender(component);
    }
}
```